# The file <filename> is locked for editing by user <username>. OWA cannot preview it too

Tags: 2013, site-collection, lock

On our SP2013 on-premises environment. We have OWA installed. Recently Excel file (.xlsx) is locked and prompt for the error at title. We confirmed the  opened the file 2 days ago. At this moment, everyone can only open it as read-only. The OWA cannot preview or open the file, too.

I understand this issue is hard to trace. However, whether any available method to unlock it by Site Collection Admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've already tried checking the document in or overriding the check out, but that there is a persistent client application lock (so it is "locked for editing" rather than "checked out").

Since you have an on-premises SharePoint farm, you can use Powershell to override this type of lock.

A farm administrator can log into one of your web front end servers, crack open the SharePoint Management Shell, then execute the following Powershell commands:

```
$web = get-spweb "http://YourSharePointEnv.com/siteurl"
$list = $web.Lists["Your Library Name"]
$item = $list.Items.GetItemById($IDofDocumentToUnlock)
$item.File.ReleaseLock($item.File.LockId)
$web.Dispose()
```

Replace `$IDofDocumentToUnlock` with whatever value is in the ID field for the locked document in SharePoint.

Comment: The answer is valid but do not help me. We cannot just walk in the server room and run PowerShell because security regulation.  I also open a question asking the client-side way to unlock. Would you please [take a look](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165970/can-we-unlock-a-shortterm-lock-via-csom-for-sp2013)?